# How to install Tom's Terrain Tool for the Unity Game Engine?

Tags: installation, terrain, unity-game-engine

I just bought and downloaded Tom's Terrain Tool but I can't find instructions for how to install it. I've looked in the downloaded file - it's a compiled file. I've looked on his website and only find instructions for what to do after it's installed. I've googled around for instructions and can't find them anywhere. In fact, the only file I got with the download is a gzip that extracts into TTT.file.  Is that the only thing that was supposed to come with the tool? Why isn't there a readme file with it? Can anyone help me out here? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't ask their support if you bought it?

Comment: Support would be me. Wondering what Lex bought, because TTT has never been a compiled file, and always came with a readme. It's a Unity package that needs to be imported into Unity 3D, maybe your unpacker messed something up?

Answer (score 1):

RoyS describes this process in his post [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/46920-I-need-some-comments-on-L3DT):

> Here's the steps I use to get my terrain into Unity.
>
> 1 - Generate your L3DT map via the Wizard if you're unfamiliar with
>   it. Then... File-->Export map-->(select) Heightfield File format -
>   (pulldown) select "RAW"
>   -type in a File Name
>   -check "resize for export"
>   -1025 size (default) Operations-->Alpha Map-->Alpha Express (png)
>
> The raw is your heightmap and the png is your splatmap. Move those to
>   your Assets folder.
>
> 2 - Make sure "Tom's Terrain Tools" is installed per his instructions.
>
> 3 - In Unity Terrain-->Create Terrain Add your 4 textures in Unity as
>   normal (you can get some nice terrain textures from
>   http://cgtextures.com ) Terrain-->Import Heightmap RAW
>   --Bit16
>   --Windows
>
> Now you should see your heightmap in your first colour chosen. If the
>   mountains are too high, then go Terrain-->Set Resolution and change
>   the 600 value. Just change those numbers until you get the desired
>   height of your mountains and valleys.
>
> Now for the rest of the colour of your terrain.
>
> In Unity, select your png texture in the Project folder and in
>   Inspector change it to ARGB 32 bit and hit the Apply button. Now you
>   won't get an error message to change it to 32 bit RBGA as you've just
>   done it. Now to add the splatmap...
>
> Terrain-->Tom's Terrain Tools-->Splatmap
>
> If you're sand is in your mountain area and your grass under the sea,
>   then just change the order of your textures until it's right (ie, the
>   terrain paintbrush textures as if you were painting one from scratch -
>   the same ones you loaded above).

Answer (score 1):

From the installation instructions [here](http://www.lemuria.org/projects/wiki/TerrainTools2/Manual):

> - Created a new terrain
>      1) Imported a heightmap
>
>   2) Calculated the light map
>
>   3) Imported all the splatmaps, treemaps, etc. you wish to use into Unity as RGB 24bit textures.
>
>   4) If using Unity 2.6, all the textures/maps you intend to use must be set to "readable" in the import settings.
>
>   5) If using Unity 3, all the textures/maps must have their Texture Type set to "Advanced" and then checked the "Read/Write
>     enabled" option.
>
> Once you're installed the Terrain Tools, you will find them in Terrain
>   => Tom's Terrain Tools in the Unity editor.